# Why does a quantum operation being trace-preserving imply that $\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k=I$?

Tags: error-correction, quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, kraus-representation

I am reading Nielsen Chuang Chapter 8. They say that if a quantum operation is trace-preserving, then
\begin{equation}
Tr\left(\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k \rho\right) = 1
\end{equation}
which I understand. They however then claim that as this is true for all $\rho$, then
\begin{equation}
\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k = I.
\end{equation}
This seems reasonable, but I cannot clearly write down the proof. Further, they say if it is non-trace preserving then $\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k \leq I$, which is something I do not understand. How are we saying one matrix is smaller than the other. Do they mean that $\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k = cI$, where $c \leq 1$ ?
However then can someone please sketch the proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that

$$
\mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_k E_k\rho E_k^\dagger\right) = \mathrm{tr}(\rho)
$$

for all $\rho$. Then

$$
\mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k\rho\right) = \mathrm{tr}(I\rho)
$$

for all $\rho$. The last equation can be rewritten in terms of [Hilbert-Schmidt inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator#Space_of_Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operators) as

$$
\left\langle \sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k,\rho\right\rangle_{HS} = \left\langle I,\rho\right\rangle_{HS}\\
\left\langle I-\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k,\rho\right\rangle_{HS} = 0
$$

for all $\rho$. Now, for any inner product $\langle .,.\rangle$, the only vector orthogonal to all other vectors is the zero vector. Therefore,

$$
I-\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k = 0
$$

and so

$$
\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k = I.
$$

---

The notation $A\le B$ means that $B-A$ is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2):

For every matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & x-iy\\x+iy & b\end{pmatrix}$(hermitian here) with real number $a,b,x,y$. And $A$ satisfy $Tr(A\rho)$ and $Tr(\rho)=1$, let's consider two by two matrix for example, we can choose $\rho=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ to make sure $Tr(A\rho)=I$. Then $A_{11}$ must be 1. For the same reason we can get $A_{22}=1$. Now $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & x-iy\\x+iy & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Furthermore, we can choose $\rho=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then to satisfy $Tr(A\rho)=I$, we have $x=0$. And by choosing $\rho=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -i\\i & 0\end{pmatrix}$, we can make sure $y = 0$.

The higher-dimensional condition can be similarly generalized.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you also please comment on what the authors mean by $\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k \leq I$ ?

Comment: [This linke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) might be helpful. Maybe someone else can describe this more reasonably.

Comment: @alpha $\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k \le I$ means $I - \sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k$ is positive semi-definite mathmatically.

Comment: @alpha let me add that $A\leq I$ for a psd matrix $A$ in particular means that all eigenvalues of $A$ are less than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by considering specific density matrices $\rho=|i\rangle\langle i|$. This immediately tells you that
$$
\langle i|\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k|i\rangle=1,
$$
and hence all diagonal elements of $\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k$ are 1. Next, consider a more general $\rho$, which we divide into diagonal and off-diagonal components,
$$
\rho=\rho_d+\rho_o.
$$
We already know that $\text{Tr}(\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k\rho_d)=1$. This must mean that $\text{Tr}(\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k\rho_o)=0$. This must also be true for any linear combinations of $\rho_o$. So, again, consider two specific instances of $\rho$:
$$
\rho=(|i\rangle+|j\rangle)(\langle i|+\langle j|), \qquad \rho'==(|i\rangle+i|j\rangle)(\langle i|-i\langle j|).
$$
By taking an appropriate linear combination, we can get the off-diagonal term $|i\rangle\langle j|$. By this token, we prove that every off-diagonal element of $\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k$ is 0. Thus, $\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k=I$.

As for the meaning of
$$
\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k\leq I,
$$
you should interpret this as the eigenvalues of $\sum_kE_k^\dagger E_k$ all being less than or equal to 1.